# Boot sequence is paused to type password for external drive (LUKS) - how to revert or skip this?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, luks

I followed a tutorial to encrypt my external HDD but I was too silly to read the whole tutorial until the end. My problem is now that my Raspberry Pi 4 doesn't boot so far that SSH service is loaded. On the monitor I can see I should type the password to mount the HDD but I have no keyboard! And I can't login to SSH because the service would be loaded after mounting the HDD.

How can I type the password or skip this step without keyboard and without SSH?

The tutorial I read is [this](http://longsteve.com/wiki/index.php/USB_Hard_Drive_Encryption_on_a_Raspberry_Pi).

Thank you.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: You've locked yourself out! Your choices are but two: Reinstall or buy/borrow a keyboard. There is no third choice. If you could "bypass" LUKS drive encryption easily, what good would it be?